# Can you call an university girl a "schoolgirl"?

Tags: word-usage

The Google definition is:

> a girl attending school. characteristic of or associated with
>   schoolgirls. modifier noun: schoolgirl "schoolgirl French"

But I'm not sure if it refers to elementary school to high school.

Can it be used for a woman who's attending university?

Comment: In AmE, 'schoolgirl' is for someone young, around elementary school age. Any older and it would be denigrating

Comment: Depends on how badly you want to be slapped.

Comment: "Schoolgirl" is old-fashioned and was used for anything prior to going to college (university).  High school might or might not be included.  I don't recommend using it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this question is the word **girl**. Most [definitions of the word "girl"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/girl) indicate that it refers to a **child**.  For that reason, it's unlikely that you would call someone in college or university a "schoolgirl." Although young women are often colloquially called "girls" even into early adulthood, it is not formal and can be perceived as demeaning. A college aged female would usually be called a **woman** in technical or professional settings. In this case, "girl" carries a childlike implication.

However, this has more to do with the age of the female than whether or not the school they attend is high school or college.  It would be appropriate to call a precocious girl who attends college at a young age a "schoolgirl."

Consider [this definition](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS734US735&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20schoolgirl) of "schoolgirl"

> characteristic of or associated with schoolgirls, **especially in being elementary or immature.**

That definition likewise implies that the term is more likely to refer to a lack of maturity or advancement of the female attending school.  So even though it can also be defined as "a girl who attends school," both definitions, through the word "girl," make it unlikely to be applied to a college or university student.